# iPhone 6+ using @1x images

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6-plus

In an app I am working on, iOS seems to be choosing the @1x images over the @2x images to display on an iPhone 6+ (picks @2x properly for a normal retina 2.0 scale screen). It was not always doing this though. I am not sure if the trigger was me adding a few @3x images or upgrading to 8.1 - both were done on the same day and I did not test on device until both had been done in several places.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: iphone 6+ uses ```@3x```. i'm not entirely sure what it will do if there is no ```@3x```, but i guess it makes sense that the default is always to fall back to ```@1x```.

Comment: It was not the default before though, it fell back to @2x (which makes a lot more sense)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.1. If only the 1x image is available, it uses the 1x image. If only 1x and 2x are available, it strangely uses the 1x instead of 2x. If 1x, 2x, and 3x are available, it uses the 3x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8.1.1 resolved this. It was clearly an iOS bug that Apple has now fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with the iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.1, built with Xcode v6.1. The problem affects images used from the bundle, but doesn't seem to affect those in an asset catalog.

- If only the 1x image is available, it uses the 1x image, as expected.
- If only 1x and 2x are available, it strangely uses the 1x instead of 2x.
- If 1x, 2x, and 3x are available, it uses the 3x, as expected.

I put together a quick asset test that I've uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/jmack/ios-asset-test).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is, to set the images via `myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];`
Like so, the `@2x` images are taken, when no `@3x` is available.
You can do this recursively for every screen.